# SELECT no valid on mysql

Tags: mysql, qt

How can I know if a SELECT access an invalid position? e.g position 651 is a not valid position in my data base but my code does not show an error:

```
query.prepare("SELECT creationDate, state FROM jobs WHERE jobId = '" + QString::number(651) + "'");
error = query.lastError().text();
if (query.exec())
{
   query.first();
   qDebug() << query.value(0).toString();
   qDebug() << query.value(1).toString();
}
else
    qDebug() << error;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your sql is valid no matter what you write as jobId. You are searching for a job with jobId 651, and wether it's there or not, the query gets executed and is therefor valid. What you want to do is get the returned rows and see if they are 0.

Comment: ok thanks, then with if(query.first()) I can check this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check if `first()` is true.

```
if (query.exec())
{
   if (query.first())
    {
       qDebug() << query.value(0).toString();
       qDebug() << query.value(1).toString();
    }
    else
    {
       qDebug() << "error";
    }
}
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#first